# Rails - Turbo - link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, preload, turbo

This is a common question on the web but I didn't found any solution for my problem...

I have the same warning message in console on all my rails apps when I click on a link to an other page

Just need to find THE solution now...

> The resource http://localhost:3000/assets/application-eda55435df3b9385974c23342a8ac80ac010272673a829df638338aed54fe933.css was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

I have no  tag in my application.html.erb but I use Turbo if it can help you

Application.html.erb

```
<head>
<title>XXXX</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= csp_meta_tag %>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbo-track': 'reload' %>

<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbo-track': 'reload', defer: true %>
</head>
```

application.js

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"

Rails.start()
ActiveStorage.start()

import "controllers"
import "bootstrap"
```

This warning is showed on development & production environments

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49674092/preloading-font-with-rel-preload . Also, to be honest, I don't see any "Preload" on the .erb you have quoted in your question. Check your actual view to see where it comes from.

Comment: @Maxence thanks but I saw a lot of this kind of solution but as you said I have no preload tag in my code neither in any of my pages, the head tag is given by my application.html.erb

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I ran into the same problem with an app that was upgraded from the Rails 6.0 default configs to Rails 7.0 (we had upgraded to 6.1 without updating the `config.load_defaults` version). It appears that this is a [default behavior introduced in 6.1](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-action-view-preload-links-header) that automatically sends the browser a "Link" header instructing it to preload assets. If you check the `Network` tab in the browser console, you should see this in the "Response Headers" section.

It seems like this is intended to improve page load performance, see item 16 [in this guide](https://lilyreile.medium.com/rails-6-1-new-framework-defaults-what-they-do-and-how-to-safely-uncomment-them-c546b70f0c5e), but it's not always appropriate. Some discussion and links are in [the PR adding the config option to disable it](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/40882) and [this Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/TheRealNooshu/status/1338428793912963076).

Note for future visitors: this can also cause problems with CSP handling, specifically for scripts loaded via `javascript_include_tag` with `nonce: true`. I found that Firefox still allowed these scripts but Safari and Chrome both blocked them, presumably because of the order in which they were loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation ! Just needed to add in the development.rb :
config.action_view.preload_links_header = false

Comment: @Loris_R did you do this in production as well? I get the warning in both envs.

Comment: @user137717 this project is not pushed in production yet, did you have any problem for production environment ?

Comment: just the same warning

Answer (score 3):

A temporary/lazy fix, and I'm not sure how this will affect performance, but the following eliminates the error in all environments:

```
config.action_view.preload_links_header = false
```